# How to create JSON in Javascript with a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have code that returns an array in json format but I want it to be under "data":
So right now, it shows as:

`"["newDate": 'test'": 'test',"attendees": 'test,"name": 'Foo']"`

How do I get it as:  `"{ data: ["newDate": 'test'": 'test',"attendees": 'test,"name": 'Foo'] }"`

```
let countries = [];
    for (x in newObj) {
        countries.push({
            "newDate": newObj[x][0],
            "count": getDates()[x].length,
            "attendees": getDates()[x],
            "name": x
        })
    }
return JSON.stringify(countries);
```

Comment: Wrap the return (`countries`) in an object with the key `data`?

Comment: try JSON.stringify({data: countries});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSON.stringify({data:countries});
```

Comment: Please post explenations with your answer, even for simple ones like these so the OP understand where they went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this argument:

```js
JSON.stringify({ data: countries });
```